# specific solution to pde $u_x + yu_y =0, u(0,y)=y^3$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have 
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
4u_{x}-3u_{y}=0\\ 
u(0,y)=y^3
\end{matrix}\right.$$

with general solution
$$u(x, y) = f(ye^{−x})$$

so using the boundary condition I get 
$ \ \ u(0,y)=y^3 \ $ so $\ \ y^3=f(ye^{0}) \quad$  therefore  $ \ \ f(y)=y^3$

which suppose give  the solution
$$u(x, y) = \mathbf{(y e^{−x})^3} = y^3 e^{−3x}$$

I don't understand the final substitution of  $\quad y \quad$  for $\quad ye^{−x}$. Could anybody explain please?

Comment: I don't get it, which step you didn't understand? By applying the initial condition, we get that $f(y)=y^3$, consider $y$ as any arbitrary value so we can replace it by $ye^{-x}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obtain the general solution $u(x,y)=f(ye^{-x})$ which is correct.

Then , with the boundary condition, you obtained $f(y)=y^3$ which is correct.

This relationship defines the function $f$

This definition of function is valid for any symbol of the variable, for example : $f(t)=t^3$ or $f(z)=z^3$ or ...

For example let :
$$f(X)=X^3$$
Thus :
$$u(x,y)=f(ye^{-x})=f(X) \text{ where } X=ye^{-x}$$
$$u(x,y)=f(X)=X^3=\left(ye^{-x} \right)^3$$ 
$$u(x,y)=y^3e^{-3x}$$